# Make button unclickable for 0.5s

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Let's say I have a button like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="action()">
     {% verbatim %}{{{% endverbatim %} submit ? submit : '{{ 'modal.actions.ok'|trans }}' {% verbatim %}}}{% endverbatim %}
 </button>
```

And I want to make it unclickable for the first 0.5s (it's inside a modal and I need some animations to load before you click the button), how could I achieve it?

Comment: If you want some animations to finish animating, then add the enable code to the animation callback.

Answer (score 3):

Set the default button state to `disabled`. Then when you trigger the modal, set a 0.5 second `setTimeout` with a function that enables the button.

See more information on [Timing Events with JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
$('#testbutton').attr("disabled", "true");
setTimeout(function(){$('#testbutton').removeAttr("disabled");}, 500);
```

You need to replace 'testbutton' with any id you give your button, or a class.